# Fonts.com font won't center

Tags: html, css, fonts, centering

I'm using the web font "FullMoonBTW01-BlkChry" from [fonts.com](http://www.fonts.com).  The text can be changed via a text box above it.  As the text gets longer, the font-size gets smaller.  The whole time, the text should be centered.

With Arial, or Times or any other "normal" font, the text centers just fine.  And even with some other fonts.com fonts it works fine, but when I try to have FullMoonBTW01-BlkChry centered, I get the following (red line is center):

[image: not centered text]

```
#myDiv .text {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    left: -3px;
    font-family: "FullMoonBTW01-BlkChry";
}
```

I've also tried increasing the 'left' to align it correctly, but depending on the dynamically changing font-size, it becomes centered, then off centered...etc.

I've also tried to eliminate any javascript alterations and just used straight-up html/css, but still WAY off-centered.

With other fonts, regardless of the size, it stays centered because it's full width and text-align:center;, but - with this font, no luck.

So - 1) why would it do this, and 2) how can I make it stay centered

**Edit:**

My HTML is literally just:

```
<div class="text">TESING</div>
```

Comment: What is your code for the containing div? Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I can't create a jsfiddle because the font-family is a paid-service from fonts.com and only works on my (or other subscribers) domain.  But my HTML is literally just what I put in the edit above.

Comment: Without a link to a live page, we can only guess at what's going on. What are those yellow dots in your screen shots?

Comment: The "yellow dots" are the cropped of tooltips that Chrome has when inspecting an element.  (an educated guess is certainly welcome)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the problem and everything checks out.

Wondering if it may be an issue with the font conversion. On Fonts.com own site it's fine though. If you change the text-align CSS setting of their font-trial tool to center the block of text it appears even.

I'm going to contact their support because it looks like there really is something wrong with the font itself.

[Page 1](http://www.suissamesser.com/test/) and [Page 2](http://www.suissamesser.com/test/index2.html)

Comment: You have exactly replicated my problem (thanks!) - it's not the text size - it's that it's **not centered** (in yours as well). I mentioned the text size because I change it dynamically so I can't just use CSS to offset by X pixels to "fake center" it ...etc.

Comment: You're absolutely right, going to contact their support out of curiosity.

Comment: Very awesome - look forward to hearing what they say. Side note - I looked for support to contact, but couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Will do. When you login you'll see there's a black box at the top that says "Need Support" in white. They usually get back in a day or so. Very strange though.

Comment: just checking in - did they reply?

Comment: Nothing yet. I bet if if something is actually wrong with the font itself it won't be a quick fix. I'll send them another note Monday if I don't hear anything.

Comment: Thank you for the test pages @jsuissa. Our preliminary testing indicates this only happens in Chromium-based browsers (Chrome, Opera Next) on Windows. We could not replicate the issue in other Windows browsers (IE, Firefox, Safari 5) or any Mac browsers (including Chrome/Opera Next). Based on that, it appears the issue may be in the Chromium engine's calls to Windows' text rendering, however, our font engineers are taking a look at this font to see if they can find anything.

Comment: @Dave, sounds like it's an issue with Chrome and possibly the font itself. I experienced the same thing, only an issue with Chrome and no issue with any other fonts from the service.

Comment: If you'd like to put the "issue w/ chrome only"...etc in your answer, i'll mark it as the answer.  Thanks.